2-Dimensional and 3-Dimensional
The numbers to the right are arranged in numerical order.

If,
 3x3 → 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4

then,
 3x3x3 → ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?


Explain your reasoning.

It gets funny when you ask 3x3x3x3 ...


 In a three-by-three layout of cells, four cells share exactly two sides apiece with other cells, four share exactly three apiece, and one shares four. Bringing that up a dimension,

we get

 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 6.


Yup, this is correct!

I got:

 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 13
 (Twelve 4's, Six 5's, Eight 7's, One 13)

Reasoning:

 For a 3x3 grid, "2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4" corresponds to the number of ways to win tic-tac-toe through each individual cell, represented in ascending order.
 For each side, there are two ways to win (horizontally, vertically).
For each corner, there are three ways (horizontally, vertically, diagonally).
For the center, there are four ways (horizontally, vertically,  2x diagonally)


 If we extend tic-tac-toe to a 3x3x3 grid (like a Rubik's cube), then we now have...
The twelve "edge pieces": 4 ways (1 along its seam, 2 across either of its faces, and 1 diagonally through the cube center)
 The six "face centers": 5 ways (4 various ways across its face as described in the 3x3 example, and 1 more through the cube center)
 The eight "corners": 7 ways (the 3 ways along its seams, the 3 diagonals across its faces, and 1 way diagonally through the cube center)
 And finally, the one "cube center": 13 ways (3 ways connecting opposing pairs of face centers, 6 ways connecting opposing edge pieces, and 4 ways connecting opposing corners)

